# x86 emulator on ARM for windows 8

Tags: 64-bit, windows-8, x86, arm

i just preordered the MSFTs Surface RT (which is an ARM-based tablet). I was wondering if it is possible through some hack(at some point in time) to install an emulator for x86/x64 apps.

I see no technical problems for this to happen, but i'm not that well aware of platform architecture shifts.

Can it be done?

Comment: Your asking if there is a Windows RT x86 emulator for a product that has not even be released yet? There isn't even a x86 emulator on ANY ARM system at this point for many many reasons let alone an unreleased product.  **"I see no technical problems for this to happen"** there are many technical reasons something like this will unlikely to happen in the near future.

Comment: This looks slightly promising, it's for linux though. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVYlrv0kbdA

Comment: @Ramhound: What technical problems?  What prevents Bochs from running on ARM?  What prevents Bochs from being ported to WinRT?  Nothing.  Lots of work, but I'm sure people are already doing it.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, there aren't much solutions for x86 emulation on ARM, but the community brought by Windows to ARM is going to be huge!

Comment: Why was this closed? This question can be answered objectively... There are no technical hurdles that make this impossible. You could cross-compile QEMU for ARM for example. The practical problems are: You'd have to hack the Windows RT device to make it run your application (since it would be a win32 / non-winrt app), or obtain a testing/microsoft signature. Also, performance would likely be not so good (it should be okay for some office/productivity apps, but not for games).

Comment: DOSBox runs on Android, meaning x86 emulation on ARM.  I think kqemu does as well.  My experience with DOSBox on a 2 core x 1Ghz phone is Wolfenstein 3d is playable but not Doom.

Answer (score 1):

It is **much** to early to say for sure, what with windows 8 only just about to be released, however, it appears something like this is feasable in the future. See this attempt at running x86 apps on linux on ARM:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVYlrv0kbdA